# Domain Model Diagram needs explanation

Tags: uml, diagram, domain-model

I'm trying to understand Domain Model Diagram and found this example diagram, I need some more help to understand this Domian Model Diagram,
Can anyone provide me links to tutorials on this or provide some guidance?

Can a boundary can be taken as a Control also(both together)? (Can we take GUI as a Control + Boundary or only as Boundary?)

I googled but couldn't find similar diagrams or tutorials as below. Please help me.

[image: Domain Model Diagram I need to understand]

Comment: -1 for not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question especially the part "..Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic..". First read a book e.g. "UML superstructure" other good links were provided by @BugFree-Solution

Comment: This one may be also useful: http://agilemodeling.com/essays/whereDoIStart.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your model **isn't domain model** at all. It's a class diagram and that's probably confusing you.

A class diagram is like a modelling tool and can be used to model some subject from different points of view, on different abstraction levels.

A Domain model is more abstract and implementation independent model of the **problem domain**. Take a look at the example proposed in a previous answer from BugFree Solution. Domain model is typically used during the **phase of analysis**, to better understand and specify the problem domain.

Your diagram shows your system structure. It's a **design artifact**. It describes your system components in terms of 3 types of classes - boundary, controller and entity.

Further in your project you might make more concrete and detailed design models, like DB data model.

In practice, all these models are very useful and complementary. It is likely that your domain model will map well on the entity classes from your diagram.